# Can you embed "commands" in JSON?

Tags: php, json, php-7

I have some JSON (let's call it `json1`), and I want to combine it with some other JSON (`json2`). I don't just want to merge or append data, I also want to be able to delete data from `json1` by embedding "commands" in `json2`.

Example

```
json1 = { 
  "a": 1,
  "b": "xyz",
  "c": ["foo", "bar"]
}

json2 = {
  "b": "hello world",
  "d": 4,
  "c": ["-foo", "+foobar"],
}

output = combine(json1, json2) 

// Expected result from the fictional "combine()" method
output = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": "hello world",
  "c": ["bar", "foobar"],
  "d": 4
}
```

Of course I could just come up with my own syntax and logic, but I'm curious if there are any existing techniques for manipulating JSON using JSON?

Disclaimer: I'm not asking about [recommendations for books, tools, software libraries (or more)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I merely have [a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](http://a%20practical,%20answerable%20problem%20that%20is%20unique%20to%20software%20development) pertaining to [a specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and am asking about [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), or possibly a [software algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Geez.

Comment: Sounds like JSON Patch documents. http://jsonpatch.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [jsonpatch](http://jsonpatch.com/) your example would translate to a `JSON Patch` similar to this:

```
[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/b", "value": "hello world" },
  { "op": "add", "path": "/d", "value": 4 },
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/c/0", "value": "foobar"}
]
```